Does the special orthogonal group of a binary quadratic form $Q$ over a field $K$ act transitively on the circle $Q(v) = r$ ($r\in K^\times$)?
Let $K$ be a field of characteristic not 2. Let $Q$ be a nondegenerate binary quadratic form over $K$. WLOG we may assume that $Q(x,y) = x^2 + ay^2$. This defines an associated bilinear form $B(v,w) = \frac{1}{2}(Q(v+w) - Q(v) - Q(w))$. The special orthogonal group $G$ is the subgroup of $SL(2,K)$ preserving $B$.
Let $r\in K^\times$. Does $G$ act transitively on the set of vectors $\{v\in K^2\;|\; Q(v) = r\}$?
The case where $r$ is a square in $K$ is equivalent to the case where $r = 1$, and I think this case should have a positive answer, though I would like to see a proof/confirmation. I'm less certain about the case where $r$ is not a square.

Yes. Probably in this case we can just write down some explicit matrices, but we can prove more generally that (still assuming that $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$) if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$ of dimension $\ge 2$ equipped with a nondegenerate quadratic form $q : V \to K$ then the special orthogonal group $SO(V, q)$ acts transitively on any sphere
$$S_r = \{ v \in V : q(v) = r \}$$
where $r \neq 0$. This can be done using geometric algebra, or equivalently the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}(V, q)$. Recall that this is the algebra generated by $V$ subject to the relations $v^2 = q(v)$ for $v \in V$, which gives $vw + wv = 2 B(v, w)$. If $v \in V$ satisfies $q(v) \neq 0$ then $v^{-1} = \frac{v}{q(v)}$ so we can define the conjugation (in the Clifford algebra)
$$\begin{align*} r_v(w) &= - vwv^{-1} \\
 &= - \frac{vwv}{q(v)} \\
 &= \frac{v(vw - 2 B(v, w))}{q(v)} \\
 &= w - \frac{2 B(v, w) v}{q(v)}. \end{align*}$$
where $w \in V$. This satisfies $r_v(v) = -v$ and $r_v(w) = w$ iff $B(v, w) = 0$ so it computes the reflection through the hyperplane orthogonal to $v$ (and since we assumed $q(v) \neq 0$, $V$ decomposes into a direct sum of $\text{span}(v)$ and $v^{\perp}$). So $\det r_v = -1$, and $r_v(w)^2 = v w^2 v^{-1} = q(w)$, which means:

Theorem: $r_v \in O(V, q)$ and any product of an even number of reflections lies in $SO(V, q)$.

Now let $v, w \in S_r$, so $q(v) = q(w) = r \neq 0$. If $v, w$ are linearly dependent, then either $v = w$ (in which case we're done) or $v = -w$, in which case the reflection $r_v$ sends $v$ to $w$, as above. Otherwise $v, w$ are linearly independent. We are going to look for a third vector $u$ such that $r_u(v) = w$. This means
$$r_u(v) = v - \frac{2 B(u, v) u}{q(u)} = w$$
so $u$ must be a linear combination of $v$ and $w$. If we write $u = av + bw$ then we need $-uvu^{-1} = w$, or $-uv = wu$, which gives
$$-(av + bw)v = -ar - bwv = w(av + bw) = awv + br$$
which rearranges to $(a + b) wv = - (a + b) r$. Since $v, w$ are linearly independent $vw$ has a nonzero bivector component so this is only possible if $a + b = 0$, hence (up to scale)
$$\boxed{ u = v - w }.$$
For this choice of $u$ to work we need $q(u) = q(v - w) = 2r - 2 B(v, w) \neq 0$, meaning we need $B(v, w) \neq r$. If $B(v, w) = r$ then $q(v + w) = 4r, q(v - w) = 0$, and $B(v + w, v - w) = 0$, so the restriction of $q$ to $\text{span}(v, w)$ is degenerate. Taking the contrapositive, we have:

Theorem: Any linearly independent vectors $v, w \in S_r$ such that the restriction of $q$ to $\text{span}(v, w)$ is nondegenerate (which implies $B(v, w) \neq r$) are related by a unique (!) reflection $r_{v-w} \in O(V, q)$.

Now observe that if we can relate $v, w$ by a reflection then we can relate them by a rotation, since (because we assumed $\dim V \ge 2$) we can find a vector $x \in w^{\perp}$ orthogonal to $w$ such that $q(x) \neq 0$ (by nondegeneracy) and apply $r_x$, which fixes $w$. So the above theorem solves the problem when $\dim V = 2$ since $q$ is nondegenerate.
When $\dim V \ge 3$ we have to argue more indirectly since it's possible for the restriction of $q$ to $\text{span}(v, w)$ to be degenerate. But by nondegeneracy we can find another vector $x \in \text{span}(v, w)^{\perp}$ such that $q(x) \neq 0$, so we can first reflect $v$ to $x$ (since $x, v$ are orthogonal) using $r_{v-x}$, then reflect $x$ to $w$ (since $x, w$ are orthogonal) using $r_{x-w}$, and the composite is a rotation.
Also the statement is false when $\dim V = 1$; in this case $S_r$ is either empty or consists of $2$ vectors $\pm v$ but $SO(V, q)$ is the trivial group. $O(V, q) = \{ \pm 1 \} $ acts transitively, though.

In the 2-dimensional case, the action of $SO(q)$ on ${q(v) = r}$ is also free right?

Do you know if the statement is true in dimension 2 for rings of integers in $p$-adic fields? (for $p\ne 2$) I.e., if $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}_p^2$, is there a unique element of $SO(q)(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ which takes $u$ to $v$? (Assume $q$ nondegenerate mod $p$)

@stupid_question_bot: 1) yes, I think so. An element of $SO(q)$ stabilizing a point also stabilizes its orthogonal complement setwise, then $\det = 1$ forces it to stabilize pointwise. 2) I don't know what happens in the non-field case; the reflection formula above requires division by $q(v)$ to work so things get more delicate. For example $SO_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a very small group, I think it's $C_4$.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ with $\dim V \geq 2$, and $char K \neq 2$.
Let $q: V \rightarrow K$ be a non-degenerate quadratic form on $V$.
If $q(v) = q(v')$, then by Witt's lemma there exists an isometry $g \in O(V,q)$ with $g(v) = v'$.
So $O(V,q)$ acts transitively on the set $S_r = \{v \in V: Q(v) = r\}$ for all $r \in K$.
Thus $SO(V,q)$ has either $1$ or $2$ orbits on $S_r$. To check that it has a single orbit, it suffices to check that $\operatorname{Stab}_{O(V,q)}(v) \not\leq SO(V,q)$ for $v \in S_r$.
To see this, take a non-zero vector $w \perp v$; then the reflection $r_w$ fixes $v$ and $\det r_w = -1$ as noted in the answer by Qiaochu Yuan.
